# Unity toggle to save password works flawlessly in Unity but doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, toggle

I have a problem with saving users login and password in PlayerPrefs. While it works very well in Unity (if the password is saved, the toggle is on on start) it doesn't work on Android (if the password is not saved, the toggle is still on on start). Before building for Android, I'm making sure that the toggle is off and password is not saved.
Here is my code:

```
void LoadUserPassOnStart(){
        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("userSaved")){
            if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("userSaved") == 1){
                loginEmail.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("savedUsername");
                loginPassword.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString("savedPass");
                saveUserPassToggle.isOn = true;

                int saved = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("userSaved");

                Debug.Log(saved);
            }
            else if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("userSaved") == 0)
            {
                saveUserPassToggle.isOn = false;
                Debug.Log("Called false");
            }
        }

    }

    void SaveUserPass(Toggle saveUserPassToggle){
        if(saveUserPassToggle.isOn){
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("savedUsername", loginEmail.text);
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("savedPass", loginPassword.text);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("userSaved", 1);
            Debug.Log("Saved");
        }
        else if(!saveUserPassToggle.isOn){
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("savedUsername", "");
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("savedPass", "");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("userSaved", 0);
            Debug.Log("Nulled");
        }
}
```

I'm calling LoadUserPassOnStart in Start(){} and I'm adding SaveUserPass to the toggle:

```
saveUserPassToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate{ SaveUserPass(saveUserPassToggle);});
```

This issue drives me nuts, will be very grateful for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the fact, that Android stores the info from PlayerPrefs even after the game is uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

try using `PlayerPrefs.Save();` after Set the keys.

Comment: Hey! I tried it, but it didn't help. When I build for Android the toggle is still on on the start during first start-up :(